# Why is `is_­destructible` defined using `declval<U&>().~U()` and not `declval<U>().~U()`?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, type-traits

By the definition of `is_destructible` (http://eel.is/c++draft/meta.unary.prop#lib:is_destructible), `is_­destructible_v<T>` is `true` when:

> Either `T` is a reference type, or `T` is a complete object type for which the expression `declval<U&>().~U()` is well-formed when treated as an unevaluated operand, where `U` is `remove_­all_­extents_­t<T>`.

Why does it use `declval<U&>().~U()` and not `declval<U>().~U()`?

The wording with `declval` was added in https://cplusplus.github.io/LWG/issue2049 to solve the problem the definition had with abstract types. Maybe the author was thinking that `declval<U>` has return type `U` so it won't work for abstract types?

Comment: At this point, looks like the only option is to ask Daniel Krugler :)

Comment: Can one reference-qualify a destructor?  `~U()&& {stuff}`?

Comment: @MooingDuck no.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

So I asked Daniel Krügler via email and he allowed me to publish his answer:

> Good question - albeit the answer is rather trivial and doesn't reveal
>   any language secret: I was aware that `std::declval<T>()` would return
>   an rvalue reference (and thus an rvalue) in the discussed context, but
>   in my mental imagination I wanted to express the picture of
>   translating `p->~T()`, which again according to the language corresponds
>   to `(*p).~T()` ([expr.ref]), so the logical consequence was to change
>   the `std::declval()` call to generate an lvalue of `T` where the
>   destructor was applied to.
>
> I'm pretty sure that I didn't believe that `declval()` was returning the
>   `T` directly, this helper function was too deeply burned into my mind ;-)